# What is the Warhammer Fantasy RPG oneshot/campaign set in an inn?

Tags: campaign-settings, product-identification, campaign, one-shot, warhammer

I was recently told about a WFRPG campaign set entirely in an inn. But I can't remember the name of it. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tracked down something claiming to be [a complete list of WFRP scenarios](https://www.scribd.com/doc/166952938/Wfrp-Complete-Scenario-List-and-Download-Links). It mentions [Trouble at the Gloating Boar Inn](https://web.archive.org/web/20020309184920/http://rpgarchive.com/index.php?page=adv1&advid=102) which matches your description.

Answer (score 5):

I also played "A Rough Night at the Three Feathers" which fits the description as well :)

You can find it [here](https://pl.scribd.com/doc/227429346/WFRP1-White-Dwarf-94-A-Rough-Night-at-the-Three-Feathers-Adventure-for-WFRP).

Comment: Can you provide a link to more information about the adventure?

Comment: Done :)

I hope you will have lots of fun with it :)

Answer (score 3):

"A Rough Night at the Three Feathers" is quite popular. It has been released in 1st as 2nd edition (respectively in "Rust in Piece" and "Plundered Vaults"). But this is standalone scenario, not a campaign. Not aware of a full campaign standing in an inn.

Details which might spoil the adventure follow:

> In "A Rough Night at the Three Feathers", the characters simply have a rest in the Three Feathers inn. But, in this Inn, they are numerous NPC that also rest who each have their own small plots conducting to many different events (brawl, murder, smuggling, etc.). Characters may involve or not in theses events. There is no big plot, just numerous events and NPC that generally make this agitated night unforgettable :) Plus, the mini-plots are quite representative of the 1st edition Warhammer flavour - no heroic action, no goblin or mutant to fight against, just humans dealing with they own feelings, relationships and situations.

Comment: The question was tagged "one-shot", so it might still be what the asker's thinking of. Given that, can you provide some more detail that would help them tell if it's the one they're thinking of or not?

Comment: Question title is tagged oneshot, but question itself seems to focus on a campaign ("a WFRPG campaign set entirely in an inn").

Comment: While that's true, keep in mind that some people use the word "campaign" quite loosely, so it's possible that it could still apply to a one-shot adventure.